# Invalid ELF file

Tags: android, shared-libraries

if I run my application on Android I always get this error and the application crashes immediately:

```
03-25 14:29:44.011  1833  7290 I ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=cz.jech.muzika/.Muzika} from uid 2000
03-25 14:29:44.093  1833  1998 I ActivityManager: Start proc 17399:cz.jech.muzika/u0a464 for activity cz.jech.muzika/.Muzika
03-25 14:29:44.098 17399 17399 E cz.jech.muzika: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
03-25 14:29:44.193  1833  2400 I WindowManager:   SURFACE show Surface(name=Splash Screen cz.jech.muzika)/@0xbe60fc9: Splash Screen cz.jech.muzika
03-25 14:29:44.298 14007 17395 D InstalledAppProviderSer: insertAppIntoDb cz.jech.muzika
03-25 14:29:44.302 17399 17414 E AndroidRuntime: Process: cz.jech.muzika, PID: 17399
03-25 14:29:44.302 17399 17414 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: invalid ELF file "/data/app/cz.jech.muzika-iMRmvRSnmwPpVhRlaZJJwg==/lib/arm64/libswscale.so" load segment[4]: p_offset (0x41000) + p_filesz (0x0) ( = 0x41000) past end of file (0x40910)
03-25 14:29:44.306  1833  9531 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity cz.jech.muzika/.Muzika
03-25 14:29:44.327  1833  4076 I ActivityManager: Process cz.jech.muzika (pid 17399) has died: vis  TOP
03-25 14:29:44.336  1140  1237 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: AppWindowToken{485887d token=Token{1c63ed4 ActivityRecord{a8f0c27 u0 cz.jech.muzika/.Muzika t4527}}}#0
```

What could be the root cause of the error? The ffmpeg libraries I use are from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avbuild/files/android/). What does the error "invalid ELF file" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The file `/lib/arm64/libswscale.so` is corrupt. In particular, it has a `PT_LOAD` segment with offset that is past the end of the file (file size is 0x40910) and has 0 length.

One way the file may have become corrupt is if you did an `FTP` transfer and forgot to set `binary` mode. (Of course there are numerous other ways, such as decompressing the archive and running out of disk space.)

Your best bet is to re-extract the archive, check the length and `md5sum` of the file, and use `scp` or something other than `ASCII` `FTP` transfer, then verify that the `md5sum` is still the same on the target device.